# What is the best way to generate client code for a CXF service?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, cxf, webservice-client

I'd like to generate a client for my CXF service so I tried the Axis 2 code generator but it doesn't quite generate straightforward-to-use code. I expected something like `client.getEmployeeByName("John Doe")` but I have to create request classes and set the parameters on them.

What is the best way to generate client code for a CXF service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just using the CXF wsdl2java command to generate the code?

Comment: Axis uses wsdl2java. Additionally, I tried using wsdl2java directly, and it generates the same kind of code. Can I get it to generate better code?

Comment: The Axis wsdl2java command and the CXF wsdl2java command are very different tools and generate different code.   You need to be clear which tool you are talking about.   The Axis version or the CXF version.

Comment: I used the Axis version. I'll try the CXF version. I'm actually surprized that there is a duplication here.

Answer (score 1):

just gave cxf a go to try to replace axis.. my goal was to replace the wsdl2java target in my maven pom files - im disapointed. 
the documentation and examples plainly sux. it appears that you have to have a local installation and reference to local resources to make the job execute (they provide a java command line based example to integrate in maven builds. it will in both examples requerre you to install something locally.

imo cxf is a nogo for client handling until they provide som industrialized tools

Comment: Uhm...  every example CXF ships uses Maven to build and they all use the cxf codegen plugin, not a command line wrapper thing.   I'm not really sure what you are describing, but it doesn't reflect the reality of how CXF and Maven are used together.